# Responsive height iPhone 8 to iPhone Pro max on React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm having a hard time to responsive my layout from `Iphone 7` to `Pro Max` or even in `Android`. On `iPhone7` my display is fine but on Pro Max there's a big space below. What's the best way to implement responsive height based from `Dimensions`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the SafeAreaView to be sure your layout is in the range for every phone 
[React Native SafeAreaView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview)

This will allow you to work in a View (which can change on every phone) but in a safe Zone to manage different phone screen.

Moreover please have a look on flex layout
[React Native Flex Layout](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox) to be sure you layout will adapt the screen.
Do not hesitate to share a piece of code if you need assistance.